# Nuance Vocalizer demo application fails to build for 64-bit simulator devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator

Trying to build the demo app contained in the DragonMobileSDK_1.4.9 download, I get 62 undefined symbols referenced from libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o, all prefixed with _nmsp_vector_.  Using Xcode 5.1.

The app compiles okay for the non-64-bit simulator devices.  When I searched for answers I saw similar posts but they were problems in user apps, resolved by linking against the same libraries as the demo app.  In this case it's the demo app itself that fails.

The build output looks like this:

```
        Ld /Users/user13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMVocalizer-gighyiitifpefcfcyeoylguzztkm/Build/    Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Vocalizer.app/Vocalizer normal x86_64
    cd /Users/user13/Developer/DragonMobileSDK_1.4.9/DragonMobileVocalizer
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/user13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMVocalizer-gighyiitifpefcfcyeoylguzztkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMVocalizer-gighyiitifpefcfcyeoylguzztkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user13/Developer/DragonMobileSDK_1.4.9/DragonMobileVocalizer -filelist /Users/user13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMVocalizer-gighyiitifpefcfcyeoylguzztkm/Build/Intermediates/DMVocalizer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DMVocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Vocalizer.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework SpeechKit -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMVocalizer-gighyiitifpefcfcyeoylguzztkm/Build/Intermediates/DMVocalizer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DMVocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Vocalizer_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DMVocalizer-gighyiitifpefcfcyeoylguzztkm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Vocalizer.app/Vocalizer

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_nmsp_audio_player_create", referenced from:
          l093 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
      "_nmsp_audio_player_delete", referenced from:
      l017 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
  "_nmsp_audio_player_getAudioSink", referenced from:
      l027 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o
…
      l069 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
      l112 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-x86_64-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Mine builds when I change architectures setting to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` in the project's build settings. Kind of worried about this with the 64 bit deadline coming up. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

Comment: Error in the SDK I guess

"Release 1.4.12 (09/11/2014)

Update to fix an issue compiling for ARM64 and XCode 6
Update to fix an issue related to arm64 compatibility for simulators and a bug where TTS audio would not play when the ringer was muted."

http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=relNotes

Answer (score 0):

You have to left only: armv7 armv7s i386 architectures for your project/demo in Architectures and Valid Architectures manually.